# How to calculate the average of multiple lists of integers?

Tags: python, list, integer, average

How to calculate the average of multiple lists of integers?

I'm having a problem, trying to get this program to calculate the average for the data in the text file.

**So this is my code:**

```
import string
from operator import itemgetter
Options=("alphabetical order","highest to lowest","average score")
Option=raw_input("Which order do you want to output?" + str(Options))
choices=("Class 1","Class 2", "Class 3")
file = open("Class1.txt","r")
#Highest to Lowest
lines = file.readlines()
loopcount = len(lines)
for i in range(0,loopcount):
    poszerostring = lines.pop(0)
    new = str(poszerostring)
    new1 = string.strip(new,'\n')
    tempArray = new1.split(',')
    resultsArray = [tempArray.append(poszerostring)]
    name = tempArray.pop()
    resultsArray.append(int(tempArray.pop()))
    resultsArray.append(int(tempArray.pop()))
    resultsArray.append(int(tempArray.pop()))
    resultsArray.remove(None)
    printedArray = resultsArray
    print printedArray
if Option == "average score":
        average = 0
        sum = 0    
        for n in printedArray:
            sum = sum(str(printedArray))
        average = sum / 3
        print average
```

Here is the data that is in the text file:

> Bob,8,5,7
>
> Dylan,5,8,2
>
> Jack,1,4,7
>
> Jay,3,8,9

Comment: @gollumbo, why did you remove all the code with your edit?

Comment: Is this part of the GCSE?

Comment: This back and forth deleting and rolling back of this question's content is ridiculous. You are posting a problem to be looked at by the public, get a decent answer and try to erase your traces afterwards? Apart from being contempt of anybody willing to help you out and putting effort in this, the question as well as @Peter's answer have already made their way into [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Cp79m7vYBlwJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/36100687/how-to-calculate-the-average-of-multiple-lists-of-integers+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de).

Answer (score 2):

You are reinventing the wheel for most of your code. I would use the `csv` package to read the file, that makes the code way cleaner. [Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html).

```
import csv

with open('Class1.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        name = row[0]  # first value on each row is a name
        values = [int(value) for value in row[1:]]  # make sure the other values are read as numbers (integers), not strings (text)
        average = sum(values) / len(values)  # note that in Python 2 this rounds down, use float(sum(values))/len(values) instead
        print('{}: {}'.format(name, average))
```

A few more pointers:

- according tot PEP8 variables (like `Options` should never start with a capital letter; classes should;
- if you are using a variable only once, you generally don't have to create it; like `loopcount` could be replaced by `for i in range(0, len(lines));
- actually, you don't need a loopcounter `i` at all, just use `for line in lines:`;
- the line `sum = sum(str(printedArray))` will overwrite the function `sum` with a value, making the function `sum` unavailable further on in the script; always avoid using variable names equal to existing function names;
- `sum(str())` won't work as excpected, because you try to add up strings, not numbers;
- you see I used `with open(file_name) as file_handler:`; this opens the file and automatically closes it at the end of the code block, thus preventing me to forget closing the file again (which you should always do); more on `with` [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Comment: good answer, might want to also explain why you use with to open the file